# Como subtrair datas no laravel?

Tags: laravel, data

Preciso calcular o tempo de trabalho em um chamado. Para isso preciso fazer operações com `date`, como faço isso no `laravel`?

*Código:*

```
 public function ticketsByUserSearch(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user = $user->find($request->user_id);
    if (!$request->initial_date) {
        $data = Ticket::where('user_id', '=', $request->user_id)->get();
    } else {
        $initial = $request->initial_date;
        $final = $request->final_date;
        $data = Ticket::where('user_id', '=', $request->user_id)
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $initial)
            ->where('created_at', '<=', $final)
            ->get();

        $jobTime = 0;
        foreach ($data as $ticket){
            $jobTime = $jobTime + ($ticket->closing_date - $ticket->created_at); //preciso de ajuda aqui
        }

        dd($jobTime);
    }
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('reports.tickets-by-user-pdf', ['data' => $data, 'user' => $user]);
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Comment: Qual é a operação com Date que você precisa fazer ?

Comment: Preciso da diferença entre horas.

Comment: Fiz a edição na resposta, e coloque dois exemplos !!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Existe um pacote instalado no [Laravel](https://laravel.com), o [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) que faz diversas operações com data. Como não disse qual operação realmente quer fazer, coloquei como exemplo a diferença entre **dias** de duas **datas**, sendo um processo simples com esse pacote.

*Diferença em dias:*

```
$date1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '1999-01-01');
$date2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2000-01-01');

$value = $date2->diffInDays($date1); // saída: 365 dias
```

*Diferença em horas:*

```
$date1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1999-01-01 15:00:00');
$date2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1999-01-01 17:00:00');

$value = $date2->diffInHours($date1); // saída: 2 horas
```

No doc Api tem até um exemplo interessante entre datas e horas em paises de localidades com fuso horário diferente

```
$dtToronto = Carbon::createFromDate(2012, 1, 1, 'America/Toronto');
$dtVancouver = Carbon::createFromDate(2012, 1, 1, 'America/Vancouver');

echo $dtVancouver->diffInHours($dtToronto); // 3
```

Site referencia:

- [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/)
- [docs Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado.

Comment: Vale lembrar que o Carbon estende o [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php), um objeto nativo do PHP que é responsável por fazer tudo isso ai =) Inclusive nos exemplos mostrados só o `diffInHours` é exclusivo do Carbon.

Comment: @gmsantos, tudo bem, espero que sim. Bom sobre os métodos que calculam diferenças, realmente o `DateTime` faz isso só que no `Carbon` está pronto e com implementações que auxiliam muito no desenvolvimento `Laravel` que é o que está na Tag. Se Quiser da um exemplo com DateTime fica a vontade quando mais respostas melhor, obrigado.

Comment: Foi só uma observação mesmo para complementar a resposta (que já está bem completa por sinal) :)