# Verificar se diferença entre datas é maior que X minutos em PHP

Tags: php

Antes de mais nada, eu já pesquisei bastante aqui no site e não encontrei nenhum exemplo mais aprofundado, apenas perguntas/respostas básicas sobre como obter a diferença entre datas, o que eu consegui fazer e funciona como eu desejo.

Porém, o código que possuo atualmente, me parece meio "pesado" mas como não possuo conhecimento avançado em PHP, não sei como poderia simplificar.

Eu possuo um arquivo JSON com alguns dados, alguns deles precisam ser atualizados quando já se passarem 30 minutos desde sua criação. Para isso eu uso o seguinte código para criar o tempo usado no arquivo json:

```
'time' => date('m/d/Y H:i:s')
```

Quando eu faço a requisição de data, faço então a comparação da data salva no arquivo json, com a data atual. Se for maior que 30minutos, eu tenho que fazer um outro tratamento. Este é o código que uso atualmente:

```
$fileTime = new DateTime($file['time']); //Data obtida do arquivo json
$currTime = new DateTime();
$interval = date_diff($fileTime, $currTime);

if($interval->y >= 1 || $interval->m >= 1 || $interval->d >= 1 || $interval->h >= 1 || $interval->i >= 30) {
    //Chama função
}
```

O problema nisso, é que se passarem 1:10 minutos e eu verificar somente os minutos, ele vai dar um resultado errado, visto que já se passaram mais de 30min, por isso eu tenho que verificar todas as casas após o minuto também.

Existe algum modo de simplificar essa verificação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sempre procuro dar uma alternativa com as funções primitivas de data, pois elas geralmente são bem simples e em vez de objetos retornam números, que são naturalmente [eficientes](https://www.dicio.com.br/eficiencia/) para operações subsequentes.

Instâncias e métodos são bons quando a abstração traz ganho e simplicidade para operações não-críticas em termos de tempo. Como no caso atual não há ganho com a abstração da DateTime, podemos fazer simplesmente isto:

```
$date1 = strtotime( '10/04/2016 15:00' );
$date2 = strtotime( '10/04/2016 16:10' );
```

Se uma das datas for a atual, pode usar isto:

```
$date1 = time(); // use mktime() para hora local
```

Para calcular a diferença:

```
$intervalo = abs( $date2 - $date1 ) / 60;

if( $intervalo > 30 ) {
   // 
}
```

Veja o cálculo no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Aa1xX3)**.

**Importante** notar que quando a data é separada por **traços**, o PHP já interpreta como `DD-MM-AAAA`, e com **barras** como `MM/DD/AAAA`. Se precisar, pode trocar assim:

```
strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '11/04/2016 18:10'));
```

O valor retornado é em segundos, dividimos por 60 para calcular os minutos.

Caso prefira, pode usar esta sintaxe caso tenha certeza que a data 2 sempre será maior que a 1:

```
$intervalo = $date2 - $date1 / 60;
```

E, obviamente, pode simplificar absurdamente o código uma vez que tenha entendido a idéia geral:

```
$date1 = strtotime( '10/04/2016 15:00' );
$date2 = strtotime( '10/04/2016 16:10' );

if( $date2 - $date1 > 1800 ) {
   // 1800 segundos = 30 minutos
}
```

<sub>Vale notar que se usar `timestamp` ou `datetime` na base de dados, em muitos DBs como mysql, você já consegue obter os valores sem precisar do strtotime até (com unix_timestamp). Economiza mais um passo, tanto em volume de dados quanto processamento do formato de data.</sub>

### Se precisar exibir o valor, ou usar tempo atual, veja esta variante:

> [Converter a diferença entre datas para string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156717/70)

Comment: Baco, estou com uma duvida, eu estou a fazer com as seguintes datas: $date1 = strtotime( '10/04/2016 15:00' );
$date2 = strtotime( '11/04/2016 18:10' ); E está me a mostrar uma diferença de 747 horas, como é possivel?

Comment: _"Quando a data é separada por traços, o PHP já interpreta como DD-MM-AAAA, e com barras como MM/DD/AAAA"_

Comment: Em outras palavras, se esse 11 é pra ser o dia, use o formato "11-04-2016". Se usa barra, está no padrao americano

Comment: E como faria com barras, para alterar o formado para dia-mes-ano?

Comment: Só trocar por traço na hora de chamar o strftime

Comment: Obrigado, Bacco!

Comment: @Gonçalo http://ideone.com/UK1RYg - e aqui tem a solução para usar o dia de hoje e mostrar em hora minuto e segundo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156717/70

Comment: Obrigado Bacco! Vou ver tudo o que me enviou.

Answer (score 2):

Pegue o valor `getTimestamp()` das duas datas e subtraia uma da outra, por fim divida por **60** que são os segundos.

```
$dt1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '04/10/2016 14:00');
$dt2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '04/10/2016 14:31');


function diff_real_minutes(DateTime $dt1, DateTime $dt2)
{
    return abs($dt1->getTimestamp() - $dt2->getTimestamp()) / 60;
}


echo diff_real_minutes($dt2, $dt1);
```

[***Exemplo funcional***](http://ideone.com/fork/75Cq4G)

Tem exemplos [**aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151697/54880) com o pacote [**nesbot/carbon**](https://packagist.org/packages/nesbot/carbon), que é um pacote para datas muito utilizado no mundo [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel), mas, pode ser instalado fora do **framework** que também tem essa lógica de cálculo apresentado acima.

```
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$data_old = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '04/10/2016 15:00');
$data_now = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '04/10/2016 15:31');

$diff = $data_now->diffInMinutes($data_old);

var_dump($diff);
```